# How to set padding, border, alignment, & edge to an ImageView

Tags: android, css, android-studio, android-layout

I'm new to Android development. I am trying to create a layout based on this image. How do I manage to align the image with a border and padding to the edge and positioned to the right? Thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: To align a view to right side of a constraint parent layout, add this attribute to your customized view:

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

& It's better to assign an ID to the container layout and to use that ID to relate the view to the parent layout. for example, my layout ID is:

```
android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
```

& aligning attribute code:

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/parent_layout"
```

Second: Paddings could be modified in the layout XML file directly to elements. There are many options to set padding, if I've understood your exact aim one of these 2 properties might be useful:

```
android:padding="planned_pad-dp"
```

or to specify different padding in height & width:

```
android:paddingHorizontal="Hor_planned_pad-dp"
android:paddingVertical="Ver_planned_pad-dp"
```

Third: To set a customized shape to the image view including the border.

a- From this path create a drawable XML file:
res->drawable->right_click->new->drawable resource file

*In the displayed window change the root property to: "shape & set other settings.

b- Use these attributes to customize your XML file:

```
<!--Defines the shape of XML file e.g.: rectangle, oval, etc.-->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="your_design">

<!--Applies required edge-->
<corners android:radius="your_edge-dp" />

<!--Applies required border-->
<stroke
    android:width="your_boarder-dp"

</shape>
```

c- Declare a relative layout in the image holder activity's or fragment's res.xml file. set its background attr. the designed XML file:

```
android:background="@drawable/your_design_drawable"
```

d- Insert your image view in the relative layout & set alignments.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the parent view you use. Using `ConstraintLayout` makes it easier to align images w.r.t sibling or parent views.

When the parent view is `ConstraintLayout`, then you can use the properties:

1. `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="viewId"`
2. `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="viewId"`
3. `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="viewId"`
4. `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="viewId"`

you can align your view with the another view with it's `id` or you align relative to your `parent` view.

This code might help you.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="your_image_reference"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: OK thank you. but how do i get the image to the right, off the edge? And how do I get the border?

Comment: what do you mean off the edge? when you use `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` the end(right) part of your image is aligned with the end(right) part of its parent view. And for border, use a custom drawable file with rectangle stroke.